# How to select field name using with relation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

[image][image][image]I am trying to get field name using with relation:

My Code:

```
public function getAllUsers()
{
    $users = User::with('userBasicInfo','roles:name')->get();

    return response([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => "All Users",
        'total' => count($users),
        'data' => $users
    ], 200);
}
```

when i simply use `$users = User::with('userBasicInfo','roles)->get();`

it returns my record accurately and when I used `$users = User::with('userBasicInfo','roles:name')->get();`

It returns my `null array` of roles I also want to display name using `roles: name` but it returns nothing.

Comment: can you update question what kind of structure you expected ? like [0] name => name , role => role ?

Comment: how is roles table connected to users or userbasicinfo table

Comment: i have created_by fk which is reference id from users tables and user_id fk in userbasicinfo table reference id on users table

Comment: The right syntax with 'with' is $users = User::with('userBasicInfo','roles:name,user_id')->get(); if there is direct relationship between roles and user.

Comment: [The docs describe exactly **Eager Loading Specific Columns**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), and explicitly mention (big red box) "_When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve._" Have you tried including the ID as specified?  The same section of the docs also describes **Eager Loading Multiple Relationships**, and show the 2 relations should be an array, ie `with(['userBasicInfo', 'roles'])`.

Comment: it works using roles:name,user_id

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
public function getAllUsers()
{
    $users = DB::table('users')
              ->select('users.name','roles.name')
              ->join('userBasicInfo', 'users.userbasicinfo_id', '=', 'userBasicInfo.id')
              ->join('roles', 'users.roles_id', '=', 'roles.id')
              ->get();
```

**OR**

```
$users = User::with(['userBasicInfo','roles:name'])->get();



    return response([
        'status' => true,
        'message' => "All Users",
        'total' => count($users),
        'data' => $users
    ], 200);
}
```

Comment: still same it returns nothing showing empty array of roles

Comment: @syed1234: Please display your database structure for users table, roles table and userBasicInfo table

Comment: i have display structure please have a look

Comment: You get empty array because no connection between users table and roles table

Comment: I have make relationships as well but still same issue